# Can't center image in UIImageView programatically

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, ios5

In UIView subclass init method I have this piece:

```
      imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 436)]; 
      imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
      [self addSubview:imageView];
      UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData: 
                        [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
                         [NSURL URLWithString: imageSource]]];
      myImage = [[MyMath sharedMySingleton] imageWithImage:myImage convertToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 436)]; // resizes image to set bounds
      imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
      [imageView setImage:myImage];
```

`imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;` should center image, but still it shows up in top left corner. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Sorry, i found answer myself. thanks to everyone

Comment: Hi, can you share your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your myImage size is equal to the size of imageView. To see the difference make your myImage size a bit smaller than that of imageView.After that it will be centered. In your one line change the size of image :

```
      myImage = [[MyMath sharedMySingleton] imageWithImage:myImage convertToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200)]; // resizes image to set bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your imageView size and myImage size are same. If you will make your myImage size to less than imageView size, you can identify the difference.